# How to control gif animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm trying to restart an animated gif on Flutter. The gif image loads from network without a problem and animates after loading. I need to restart the animation on tapping a button.

Tried so far:
- setState
- change Key to some other unique key and setState to rebuild.

Solution as @chemamolins 's suggestion:

```
int _robotReloadCount=0;
```

....

```
GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
  onTapRobot();
},
child: Center(
  child: Container(
   margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 55.0, bottom: 5.0),
   height: 150.0,
   width: 150.0,
   child:
    FadeInImage(
      key: this._robotImageKey,
      placeholder: AssetImage('assets/common/robot_placeholder.png'),
      image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data['robot_image_path'] +"robot_level" +snapshot.data['robot_level'].toString() +".gif"+"?"+this._robotReloadCount.toString()))),
  ),
),
```

....

```
onTapRobot() async{
    setState(() {
      this._robotReloadCount++;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please, provide the code you are working on. If you show your code we could help you with suggestions based on it.

Comment: This is a generic issue, not just related to code. I'm adding the solution @chemamolins suggested.

Answer (score 8):

I have done a lot of tests and it is not easy. The image is cached by the 'ImageProvider' and whatever you change or no matter the times you invoke `build()` the image is loaded from what is available in the cache.

So, apparently, you only have two options.

Either you rebuild with a new url, for instance by appending `#whatever` to the image url.

Or you remove the image from the cache as shown in the code below.

In either case you need to fetch again the image from the network.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String url = "https://media.giphy.com/media/hIfDZ869b7EHu/giphy.gif";

  void _evictImage() {
    final NetworkImage provider = NetworkImage(url);
    provider.evict().then<void>((bool success) {
      if (success) debugPrint('removed image!');
    });
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(
        child: Image.network(url),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _evictImage,
        child: new Icon(Icons.remove),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the only and best option for now. Added a ?reloadcount after the url, on FadeInImage.

Comment: You can avoid re-fetching from the network by just keeping the bytes around and using a `MemoryImage` instead.